# Qt/PyQt - frequently drawing pixmap to widget, partly not drawing correctly

Tags: qt, graph, plot, pyqt, real-time

I'm working on a Qt based application (actually in PyQt but I don't think that's relevant here), part of which involves plotting a potentially continuous stream of data onto a graph in real time.

I've implemented this by creating a class derived from `QWidget` which buffers incoming data, and plots the graph every 30ms (by default). In `__init__()`, a `QPixmap` is created, and on every tick of a `QTimer`, (1) the graph is shifted to the left by the number of pixels that the new data will take up, (2) a rectangle painted in the space, (3) the points plotted, and (4) `update()` called on the widget, as follows (cut down):

```
    # Amount of pixels to scroll
    scroll=penw*len(points)

    # The first point is not plotted now, so don't shift the graph for it
    if (self.firstPoint()):
        scroll-=1

    p=QtGui.QPainter(pm)
    # Brush setup would be here...

    pm.scroll(0-scroll, 0, scroll, 0, pm.width()-scroll, pm.height())
    p.drawRect(pm.width()-scroll, 0, scroll, pm.height())        

    # pen setup etc happens here...

    offset=scroll

    for point in points:
        yValNew = self.graphHeight - (self.scalePoint(point))

        # Skip first point
        if (not(self.firstPoint())):
            p.drawLine(pm.width()-offset-penw, self.yVal, pm.width()-offset, yValNew)

        self.yVal = yValNew
        offset-=penw

    self.update()
```

Finally, the `paintEvent` simply draws the pixmap onto the widget:

```
    p = QtGui.QPainter(self)
    p.drawPixmap(0, 0, self.graphPixmap)
```

As far as I can see, this should work correctly, however, when data is received very fast (i.e. the entire graph is being plotted on each tick), and the widget is larger than a certain size (approx 700px), everything to the left of the 700px area lags considerably. This is perhaps best demonstrated in this video: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1362366/keep/Graph_bug.swf.html (the video is a bit laggy due to the low frame rate, but the effect is visible)

Any ideas what could be causing this or things I could try?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if this is the problem or not, but I thought I might make at least some contribution.

`self.update()` is an asynchronous call, which will cause a paint event at some point later when the main event loop is reached again. So it makes me wonder if your drawing is having problems because of the sync issue between when you are modifying your pixmap vs when its actually getting used in the paintEvent. Almost seems like what you would need for this exact code to work is a lock in your paintEvent, but thats pretty naughty sounding.

For a quick test, you might try forcing the event loop to flush right after your call to update:

```
self.update()
QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()
```

Not sure that will fix it, but its worth a try.

This actually might be a proper situation to be using `repaint()` and causing a direct paint event, since you are doing an "animation" using a controlled framerate: `self.repaint()`

I noticed a similar question to yours, by someone trying to graph a heart monitor in real time: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/10677
Maybe you could try restructuring your code similar to that. Instead of splitting the painting into two stages, he is using a QLabel as the display widget, setting the pixmap into the QLabel, and painting the entire graph immediately instead of relying on calls to the widget.update()